# Wrong fprintf output in c

Tags: c, file, pointers, fopen, printf

So here is the code that I am attempting to get to work:

```
char* inFile = "input.txt";
FILE *out = fopen("output.txt", "a+");
int i = 0
while(i < 5){
            int countFound = findWord(inFile, keyWord[i]);//returns count of keywords in given file
            fprintf(out, "%s: %d\n", keyWord[i], countFound);
            i++;
        }
fclose(out);
```

The output of this code is:

```
youshouldsee1
: 3
youshouldsee2
: 3
youshouldsee3
: 3
youshouldsee4
: 3
youshouldsee5: 1
```

Expected output:

```
youshouldsee1: 3
youshouldsee2: 3
youshouldsee3: 3
youshouldsee4: 3
youshouldsee5: 1
```

I don't really understand why the output is like that, shouldn't it print the string and the int then a new line? Also note that there is not a newline after the last line and there should be. I did some testing and I noticed that if I changed the `fprintf` statement to `fprintf(out, "%s\n", keyWord[i]);` the output is:

```
youshouldsee1
youshouldsee2
youshouldsee3
youshouldsee4
youshouldsee5
```

Which is formatted much better. Again note that there is not a newline after the last line and there should be.
I noticed that while doing this with just `printf` statements I get the exact same problem, but the output is slightly more messed up.

Does anybody know what causes this specific issue? Much appreciated.

The array keyWord[] is a double pointer, I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not, but I thought that I would mention it. It is declared like so `char** keyWord;`. And it was created as follows:

```
char *tempWord = "something";
keyWords[x] = strdup(tempWord);
```

That could be totally irrelevent but I thought it was best to mention it.

Comment: The keyword string must have newlines at the end of them.

Comment: Please add declarations of all variables, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: @Gene, When I am creating the string or when I am using fprintf?

Comment: @hyde, Sorry Im on it.

Comment: If you just comment out the `findWord` call and instead `countFound` to `0`, does it give properly formatted output then then? If yes, problem is in `findWord` function somewhere.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you seek to start of file after you've processed it with `findWord` for one word? (So for an efficient solution, you might want to rethink the whole thing, but I suppose it does not matter at this point.)

Comment: @hyde, I commented out the `findWord` and made `countFound = 0;` The output was the same.

Comment: Well, code looks right. As next step, I'd look at hex dump of the `keyWord[...]` contents. Use debugger or (google for and) add a hex dump function. Look for `'\n'` and `'\r'` chars (LF and CR, 0A and 0D in hex) or other chars with hex ASCII code <= 1F.

Comment: When you create the keyword strings. Each keyword must have a newline at the end.  This is the only explanation for the newlines appearing in the output when there's none in the fprintf.  Whatever you're passing to `strdup` already has the newline in it.

Comment: @user2856537 You need to make your soulution an answer, not a part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have some carriage return characters (`'\r'` or 0x0D) and/or backspace characters (`'\b'` or 0x08) in your `keyWord[i]` strings.

CRs and backspaces don't print ordinarily to terminals and instead move the terminal cursor—CRs move the cursor to the beginning of the current line, and backspaces move the cursor backwards one character.  When subsequent characters are printed, they *overwrite* what was there before.  So this code

```
printf("foobar\rbaz\n");
```

results in this output

```
bazbar
```

and this code

```
printf("foo\bbar\n");
```

results in this output

```
fobar
```

If you look at the raw bytes of the output without printing it to the terminal, you should see the CRs and backspaces plain as day.  I like to use the program [`hexdump(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump) to do that.  For example:

```
$ echo -e 'foobar\rbaz'
bazbar
$ echo -e 'foobar\rbaz' | hexdump -C
00000000  66 6f 6f 62 61 72 0d 62  61 7a 0a                 |foobar.baz.|
0000000b
```

So I'd suggest looking at the raw data in your program's output and find out where the pesky characters are, and then figure out how to get rid of them.